# How do I setTimeout() in Framer, which uses coffeeScript?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, settimeout, framerjs

I would like to trigger a function after a delay. In Javascript I usually use `setTimeout(function(), t)`.
How can I do this in framerJS?

Answer (score 2):

Answer:

```
Utils.delay time, -> functionName()
```